# Python log call gets executed infinitely

Tags: python, django, python-requests, uwsgi

We've been seeing some weird behaviour in our application, where a log statement gets executed infinitely. This issue happens on both local and production systems. Our stack is a simple uWSGI/Django stack, so it doesn't seem to be related to either uWSGI or Whiskey.

We have not been able to reproduce the issue, sometimes days go by without the issue rearing it's ugly head, but there is always a very clear pattern:

```
logger.info('Beginning download')
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
logger.info('Downloading %s' % url)
```

And in our logs:

```
Beginning download
Downloading http://XXX
Downloading http://XXX
Downloading http://XXX
Downloading http://XXX
Downloading http://XXX
Downloading http://XXX
Downloading http://XXX
Downloading http://XXX
```

until either you manually kill whiskey or uWSGI harakiri's.

Whether you use `requests.get`, `requests.post`, or whatever method, it doesn't seem to matter.

The actual network requests does not seem to be executed `N` amount of times. Just the log that gets written to file or stdout an infinite amount of time.

**Edit** Here is the source in [Context](https://gist.github.com/briandeheus/fb5dd53d21f650939b34437a64a9938b)

It happens in other parts of the code as well, always after calling the requests library. It doesn't matter which URL we call. We interface with S3, various social media APIs, and the behaviour exhibits itself across all type of URLs.

Comment: Have you checked for circular references?

Comment: Please show us the full view code.

Comment: @wwii if it was an issue with circular references, wouldn't this bug be easy to replicate?

Comment: @solarissmoke I'll add parts of the source code. Naturally it's a proprietary codebase so I can't show you the full source.

Comment: Uneducated guess - I looked at the symptom and two things popped into my head -" that looks like an echo" and "maybe a circular reference".  Can you add any object information in the log message?  Are there multiple things that make that log? Is it one thing that gets created and *destroyed* multiple times?  I don't know anything about django.